# create nsmutablearray dynamically

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

Trying to create dynamic `NSMutableArrays` in a foor loop

```
//Here's my for loop
for (Object *object in parseMethod.objects) {

}
```

`objects` is an `NSMutableArray` which stores the objects; based on the number of the objects I'd like to create unique array, something like:

```
NSMutableArray *array1;
NSMutableArray *array2;
NSMutableArray *array3;
//and so on...
NSMutableArray *array[n];
```

Anyone can share an answer how to achieve this?

Comment: What about creating another one `NSMutableArray` that will store other `NSMutableArray`'s?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish or how is it going to be used?

Comment: @Zaph: Trying to create dynamic arrays that will store some items; I have a method which parses an XML and for each item from the XML file I'd like to create a array in which I have to add objects...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understood your problem, but I think you want to create a number of arrays, based on the number of objects in another array, right? If so, try this:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayWithOtherArraysInIt = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[objectsClass count]];

for (objectClass *object in objectsClass.objects) {

   [arrayWithOtherArraysInIt addObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0]];

}
```

**Edit:** Oh and by the way, you should think about your naming conventions. You're not supposed to use lowercase class names (like you did with objectClass). And I wouldn't name an object directly after its class' name...